# Find a limit of a weird function

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

We have this function:

$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & x \in \mathbb{Z}  \\[2ex]
1, & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Z} 
\end{cases}
$

Find if these limits exist:

$
\lim_{x\to  \infty}   f(x)
$

$
\lim_{x\to  2} f(x)$

$
\lim_{x\to  2.5}  f(x) $

If not, prove it.

It's clear that there's a limit when $ x \to 2.5 $ but I'm having trouble proving it using the defnition of the limit,

any help?

thanks :)

Comment: The limit as x approaches 2 is 0. The limit as x approaches 2.5 is 0. In fact, the limit as x approaches any point is 0. This is essentially the 0 function with a countable number of discontinuities.

Comment: This is clear, can you pleae show me how to prove for $x \to 2.5 $ ? :S

Comment: For all e > 0 we can choose some d > 0 such that for all |x - 2.5| < d we have |f(x) - 0| < e. We just have to choose some sufficiently small d. Say we choose d = 0.000005. We know for all x within 0.000005 of 2.5 that f(x) = 0, and f(x) - 0 < e for all e > 0.

Comment: Fyi, this type of function is called an "indicator" function, which is 1 for a subset of a bigger set and 0 outside.  So this would be the non-integer indicator function on the Reals.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for that tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

---

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist because:

- $\forall x : f(x)=0 \implies f(\lceil{x}\rceil)=1$
- $\forall x : f(x)=1 \implies f(x+\frac12)=0$

In other words, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist because:

- For every $a$ such that $f(a)=0$ there exists $b>a$ such that $f(b)=1$
- For every $a$ such that $f(a)=1$ there exists $b>a$ such that $f(b)=0$

---

$\lim\limits_{x\to2.5}f(x)=0$ because:

- $\forall\epsilon:|\epsilon|<0.5 \implies f(2.5+\epsilon)=f(2.5-\epsilon)=0$

In other words, $\lim\limits_{x\to2.5}f(x)=0$ because:

- For every $\epsilon$ close enough to zero, $f(2.5+\epsilon)=f(2.5-\epsilon)=0$

Comment: Can you update your question now about $x \to 2.5$ ?? I accidentally posted it wrong. thanks

Comment: @user1326293: I don't understand (I didn't post any question, you did).

Answer (score 0):

2) The limit at $2$ is $0$ as all values around $2$ are $0$.

3) The limit at $2.5$ is $0$ as all values around $2.5$ are $0$.

1) There is no limit at $\infty$ as there are infinitely many $0$'s and $1$'s around $\infty$.